# Details of Pentaho Data Integration ( ETL kettle tool)

Tags: mysql, pentaho, etl, kettle

I need to convert the contents of Excel sheet to the corresponding tables in MySQL database. I referred the net and found that Pentaho data integration (ETL Kettle tool) can be used for this purpose. Can anyone suggest me which version can I download the software and tutorials on those ETL tools?

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) site itself. You can download the latest version from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that covers the sort of transformations you are looking to do. While this tutorial uses .csv files as the data sources, you could just as easily substitute Excel files as the source. http://holowczak.com/building-etl-transformations-in-pentaho-data-integration-kettle/